# drf social-oauth2 access_denied ,Your credentials aren't allowed

Tags: python-social-auth

I'm trying to use this package https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

In ***Google Example***

When I try to request an access_token by

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<django-oauth-generated-client_id>&client_secret=<django-oauth-generated-client_secret>&backend=google-oauth2&token=<google_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token
```

it's saying

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Your credentials aren't allowed"}
```

What should I put in

```
django-oauth-generated-client_id and django-oauth-generated-client_secret
```

is that the thing where you create new application or should I put the google's client and secret ids

I try both but still not working.

Also in

```
token=<google_token>
```

I try to put the Authorization code or the access_token in this image but still not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RKP3.png)

Can someone help thank you

Comment: It's possible the access_token from Google has expired. Do further testing on the google playground, `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/`. Under `Step 1: Select & authorize APIs`, choose Google oAuth2 API to test, you can use the access token in Step 3 to test with your local API